# How do I use window.open(parameter) and not include the current website path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am retrieving a url in a string (result) from an MVC controller method and want to open that url in a new window. The result string is good, but when I hit the window.open(result) line it opens a new window and tries to load a url with my current domain path appended to the front of the 'result' string, which of course causes an error. How can I keep from appending the local domain path in front of the 'result' parameter when executing the window.open() method.

**'result' looks like this**: `https://globalmapi.alipay.com/gateway.do?secondary_merchant_industry=5799\u0026_input_charset=utf-8\u0026subject=This+is+a+test\..........`

**the url in the new page looks like this**: `http://localhost:50063/Home/%22https://globalmapi.alipay.com/gateway.do?secondary_merchant_industry=5799\u0026_input_charset=utf-8\u0026subject=This+is+a+test\.............`

I have cut the string short due to credentials, etc. but I have to think you can see the issue.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Method", "MVC Controller")',
  type: "Post",
  data: {
    Amount: $("#trans_amount").val(),
    Description: "This is a test",
  },
  dataType: "text",
  cache: false,
  success: function (result) {
    window.open(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: `result` should be an absolute URL.

Comment: What form is `result`? Is it its own full URL, and you're getting something like `https://my.website.com/https://result.com/`, or is it a single string/path? Please show us. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I am getting something like https://my.website.com/https://result.com/

Comment: result looks like this:  https://resultWebsite.com

Comment: To clarify result has several paths and parameters included: https://globalmapi.alipay.com/gateway.do?secondary_merchant_industry=5444\u0026_input_charset=utf-8\u0026subject=This+is+a+test\.........

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue with your MVC Controller? `@Url.Action()` doesn't look like anything in the regular JavaScript API, so I am led to believe that you have something else at play. Perhaps try adding some different tags for all of the software you're using to try and get some more eyes on your problem.

Comment: Usually it's the browser filling relative addresses, not the server. Browsers are checking if there's the protocol and host part, and if those are missing from an url, the current domain is added to the url. Sorry, but I've to ask this, did you really check the value of `result` in `success` callback function, or did you just told us a value you expect to get from your server?

Comment: Teemu of course I did check it several times..I believe for some reason when the window.Open() method runs it is inserting the un-wanted host, however it may be an MVC issue too, so I am now trying to call the url from c#, but having an issue with return Redirect(). Do you see a problem with my code below. 'alipayUrl' is correct.
string alipayUrl = apiResult[0].webpay_url;
return Redirect(alipayUrl);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue and thought someone else might benefit from my research.
I gave up on using window.open() and decided to try to open the new website directly from c# using return Redirect(), which also failed...??
However, during my research I found a great solution:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myParameter);
This goes right down into your system and pops a new browser with the correct url.
Hope this helps someone.
Thanks to all who have look at this.

Comment: Disclaimer: This solution did not work once I published to my server.